# Getting Defect severity list Pyral

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rally, pyral

Is there a way with Pyral to get a list of the different defects severitys?  I can query by severity type like:

```
severity=rally.get(entity='Defect', fetch=True, query=['Severity = "Serious"'])
```

and that gives all of the defects with severity "Serious"  but how can I find all of the different severity types besides debugging?

Answer (score 1):

In the pyral repository on GitHub in the 'examples' folder there are a couple of files to list Allowed Values and the Schema.

Allowed Values: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/blob/master/examples/allowedValues.py

Schema: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/blob/master/examples/get_schema.py

You may also use the Agile Central Web Services API documentation to view all the information as well.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/